# Space Marine Attack Bike Twin-Linked bolter

Tags: warhammer-40k

According to page 62 of the Codex: Blood Angels (5th), the Space Marine Bike are equipped with twin-linked bolter.

According to the army list, neither Attack Bike Squad nor Bike Squad mentions this option.

My understanding is that even if not mentionned in the army list (and not errata has been written on this), the attack bike will thus have the TL bolter + a heavy bolter. Both SM on the bikes also carry a bolter pistol.

My understanding is that during the shooting phase I can fire both TL bolter and heavy bolter (same target)? Or that I can fire the heavy bolter and a bolter pistol, or even just two bolter pistols.

Am I correct?

Now, if an attack bike loses a life point (out of two), can I still fire both TL bolter and heavy bolter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a bike you can fire as many weapons as there are riders.  So an attack bike can fire up to two weapons since it has two riders.  This is regardless of how-many wounds the bike has sustained.

The entry for the the Space Maine bike in the equipment list will indicate which weapons it has.  Much like the entry for Terminator Armor indicates that it allows deep-striking. The twin linked bolter is mentioned there.

And there is no good reason to shoot anything but the heavy weapon and the twin linked bolter.  You suffer no penalties for using them on a bike and are hands down a better option than the pistol in every way.

Comment: That's what I though: why the hell do they carry pistols?

Answer (score 1):

Bikes have the relentless rule so you can always rapid fire the twinlinked bolter as well as the heavy bolter, the only think that will stop you firing is turbo boosting.

In answer to your second question in the comment the bikers carry a pistol to gain a second attack if you arm then with a close combat weapon.

My biker seargent has a power axe so when he get into combat he has and axe and a pistol so gets an extra attack for two close combat weapons.

It is commonly understood that the codex overules the rulebook where rules differ.